# SCSS transition property overwrite

Tags: css, sass, css-transitions, mixins

I use a @mixin to add different transition properties to elements. Let's say I have this in my .scss:

```
@mixin transition($prop, $sec){
  -webkit-transition: $prop $sec;
  -moz-transition: $prop $sec;
  -ms-transition: $prop $sec;
  -o-transition: $prop $sec;
  transition: $prop $sec;
}
```

then I call:

```
.sample{
  @include transition(background-color, 0.2s);
  @include transition(margin, 0.3s)
}
```

.sample has only got margin transition, but I also want background-color transition: is there any simple way to get it working?

It's important that I have different calls

Comment: This mixin syntax is wrong, there isn’t commas between transition values. Also you can’t apply multiple values with the shorthand `transition`, you have to use `transition-property`. I’ll try to give you some code in an answer.

Comment: @leBen yeah, wrote it in a rush... sorry

Comment: FYI, the `-ms-` prefix is not needed.

Comment: You're going to have to provide a use case for this "different calls" necessity.  You could write a horrible kludge to do it, but I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: let the horrible kludge be

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way in SASS to concatenate properties and I don't know if exists a CSS external tool to do this task. Sass was created to improve CSS capabilities and not to allow programmers to develop bad programming practices. I don't really know the purpose of create multiple CSS declaration statements when you can keep them all in a single statement. Keeping all your transitions in one statement improves considerably your structure, your workflow and the performance of your Sass code.

**Ok, that said, and as you have mentioned before "let the horrible kludge be".**

Here are two different mixins for you one for shorthand transition declaration and another for the long form, differences between them in processing and even load time are negligible, the only noticeable difference is in the style of your code.

**Long form mixin**

```
@mixin transition($properties, $durations, $timing-function: null, $delay: null) {
  $declarations: (property, $properties),
                 (duration, $durations),
                 (timing-function, $timing-function),
                 (delay, $delay);
  
  @each $declaration in $declarations {
    @if nth($declaration, 2) {
      $output: ();
        @each $val in nth($declaration, 2) {
          $output: append($output, $val, comma);
        }
      @each $prefix in '-webkit-', '-moz-', '-ms-', '-o-', '' {
        #{$prefix}transition-#{nth($declaration, 1)}: $output;
      }
    }
  } 
}
```

It's similar to @LeBen mixin but you can use the include with comma separated arguments without quotes:

```
@include transition(background-color margin, 0.2s 0.3s);
```

---

**Shorthand form**

```
@mixin transition($declarations...) {
  @each $prefix in '-webkit-', '-moz-', '-ms-', '-o-', '' {
    #{$prefix}transition: $declarations;
  }
}
```

Here's the way to implement it in your code

```
@include transition(background-color 0.2s, margin 0.3s);
```

And now, to solve your problem with "different calls" the only way to deal with them, in my opinion, is using [`append()`](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#append-instance_method) list function.

Let's go with the example. I'm going to use shorthand mixin form because it's easier to implement.

Imagine that you have four pages, three partials (`_variables.scss`, `_page1.scss`, `_page2.scss`, `_page3.scss`) and a `style.scss` file which imports the other:

**_VARIABLES.SCSS**

```
// Here comes the variable declaration
$transition-list: color 1s;
```

**_PAGE1.SCSS**

```
// Using append($list, $val, $separator:auto) list function
// we can add some items to $transition-list
$transition-list: append($transition-list, margin 2s, comma);
```

**_PAGE2.SCSS**

```
// You can add also the output of a function
@function example(){
  @return unquote("background-color 1s")
}

$transition-list: append($transition-list, example(), comma);
```

**STYLE.SCSS**

```
// You can add new values into the same page
$transition-list: append($transition-list, padding 4s, comma);

$transition-list: append($transition-list, border 10s, comma);

// And finally you only need to use the include to generate the final transition
example {
  @include transition($transition-list);
}
```

As I've said before, **I don't recommend to use this method**, it's not a good practice.

Answer (score 3):

Your mixin is too rigid and don't feel like natural CSS.  Personally, I recommend using the [mixins provided by Compass](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/css3/transition/), especially since it should handle prefixed values as well.  If you just want a simple mixin, you want to use variable arguments like so:

```
@mixin transition($values...) {
    -webkit-transition: $values;
    // other prefixes
    transition: $values;
}

@mixin transition-property($values...) {
    -webkit-transition-property: $values;
    // other prefixes
    transition-property: $values;
}
@mixin transition-delay($values...) {
    -webkit-transition-delay: $values;
    // other prefixes
    transition-delay: $values;
}

// etc

.foo {
    @include transition(background-color, margin); // or transition-property
    @include transition-delay(0.2s);
}
```

Output:

```
.foo {
  -webkit-transition: background-color, margin;
  transition: background-color, margin;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.2s;
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
}
```

Alternate Usage:

```
.foo {
    @include transition(background-color 0.2s, margin 0.3s);
}
```

Output:

```
.foo {
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.2s, margin 0.3s;
  transition: background-color 0.2s, margin 0.3s;
}
```

Comment: the point was transition properties overlapping, not how to use mixins

Comment: Did you test this to verify that it doesn't work or are you just *assuming* that I misunderstood the question?

Comment: my prob was transition-property being overwritten by the next definition, and wanted to avoid that, hoping that scss might have a solution to this. What you did was simply provide me a function for making it. The other answerer did aswell, and none of you have helped me, I solved my problem myself, so decided to close this question and give the answer correct to who wrote the most detailed answer, and he was

Comment: If you answered the question yourself, then the correct course of action is to post your answer and accept *that*, not just give the checkmark to someone at random.  Choosing a wrong answer does not help future visitors.

Comment: I totally get what you mean, but my answer would be simply to find a way around that, and would probably not be helpful to other viewers either, and I didn't think about other viewers, so I'm going to uncheck his answer as correct and wait for someone with the right answer

Answer (score 0):

Here is the mixin you could use:

```
@mixin transition($properties, $durations, $timing-function: null, $delay: null) {
  $props: unquote($properties);
  $durs: unquote($durations);

  -webkit-transition-property: $props;
     -moz-transition-property: $props;
      -ms-transition-property: $props;
       -o-transition-property: $props;
          transition-property: $props;

  -webkit-transition-duration: $durs;
     -moz-transition-duration: $durs;
      -ms-transition-duration: $durs;
       -o-transition-duration: $durs;
          transition-duration: $durs;

  @if ($timing-function) {
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: $timing-function;
       -moz-transition-timing-function: $timing-function;
        -ms-transition-timing-function: $timing-function;
         -o-transition-timing-function: $timing-function;
            transition-timing-function: $timing-function;
  }

  @if ($delay) {
    -webkit-transition-delay: $delay;
       -moz-transition-delay: $delay;
        -ms-transition-delay: $delay;
         -o-transition-delay: $delay;
            transition-delay: $delay;
  }
}
```

With the following call

```
@include transition("background-color, margin", 0.2s);
```

Comment: There's one last property that's missing and that is `transition-delay`.

Comment: It doesn’t seem to be required by @t1wc (as the timing-function) but it could be easily added, I agree.

Comment: Yeah, just for the sake of completeness :)

Comment: Here it is, optional timing-function and delay ;-)

Comment: @leBen it's also required that I call
   `@include transition(background-color, 0.2s); `
   `@include transition(margin, 0.2s);`
and if I want different timings?

Comment: I’ve updated the mixin so it can support multiple duration. You can do it for timing-function as well, simply unquote the variable before using it in the mixin. `@include transition("background-color, margin", "0.2s, 0.4s")`

Comment: @LeBen but I want to add the stuff not in just 1 go, but in different ones

Comment: Can you explain why it is important? I will certainly help us answer your question.